# Missing Nsight Menu Visual Studio 2015

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015, cuda, visual-studio-debugging, nsight

First of all , i have the following specs:

-Visual studio 2015Pro version: 14.0.25123.00 update 2

-Nvidia GeForce GTX 765M (i know it is not in the supported gpus list)

-Nsight 5.1 and Nsight 6.0 installed

-CUDA toolkit 8.0 installed

-Nvidia Driver version : 416.16 installed

-Microsoft Windows 10 64bit

My problem is that **Nsight menu is missing** in Visual Studio and I'd like to start CUDA debbuging.

The things that I have tried:

First I have installed Nsight 6.0 then 5.1 (i restarted my PC) still missing Nsight menu(I actually can't find Nsight in my *VS Extensions and Updates* box).Then updated to the latest Nvidia Driver(I have read the manual of it but I could not find if it is CUDA debugging capable).

My visual studio is installed on X:\ drive but I have the following shortcuts pointing to where Nsight is located on C:\
[Shortcuts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1UL9.jpg) I've read in a different topic I must have these.

The story behind it:

I am developing a filtering program which is not working properly , I have followed the steps the program makes but I need to use the debugger.

At this point I am asking for some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated my VS2015 to update3 also installed CUDA toolkit 10 and now the nsight menu is showing.